# Impressão dos registros de um arquivo

Tags: c

Eu estou fazendo um programa em c, que vai ler os registros de um arquivo e passar o nome contido nos registros para uma lista duplamente encadeada onde serão ordenados por ordem alfabética, e depois com ajuda da lista os registros do arquivo serão imprimidos em ordem.

Esse é o código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct registro{
char matricula[5];
char nome[50];
char genero;
float salario;
char cargo;
char setor[2];
}registro;

typedef struct tiplista{
struct elem *inicio;
struct elem *fim;
}tiplista;

typedef struct elem{
char nome[50];
struct elem *ant;
struct elem *prox;
int pos; // posição do elemento no arquivo binário
}elem;

void insercao_lista_ordenada(tiplista *lista, char nome[50], int posicao){
    elem *aux;
    elem *novoelemento=(elem*)malloc(sizeof(elem));
    strcpy(novoelemento->nome,nome);
    novoelemento->prox= NULL;
    novoelemento->ant= NULL;
    novoelemento->pos=posicao;
    if(lista->inicio == NULL){ //lista vazia

        lista->inicio=novoelemento;
        lista->fim=novoelemento;

    }else{

        aux = lista->inicio; // pont aux recebe o ponteiro do início da lista
        while ((aux->prox != NULL) && (strcmp(aux->nome, nome) < 0))
        {
            aux = aux->prox;

        }
        // verificar se a inserção no início
        if ((aux == lista->inicio) && ((strcmp(aux->nome, nome)) > 0))
        {

            novoelemento->prox = lista->inicio;
            lista->inicio->ant = novoelemento;
            lista->inicio = novoelemento;

        }
        else if ((strcmp(aux->nome, nome)) < 0) // elemento a ser inserido maior
            {

                // verificar se a inserção no final
                if (aux == lista->fim)
                {
                    novoelemento->ant = lista->fim;
                    lista->fim->prox = novoelemento;
                    lista->fim = novoelemento;

                }
                else // inserção no meio
                {
                    novoelemento->ant = aux->ant;
                    aux->ant->prox = novoelemento;
                    novoelemento->prox = aux;
                    aux->ant = novoelemento;

                }
            }

    }

return;
}

void imprimir_lista(tiplista *lista)
{
    elem *aux;
    registro reg;
    FILE *arq_bin_p;
    if((arq_bin_p=fopen("arq_bin_principal.bin","rb")) == NULL){
        printf("Erro: não foi possível encontrar o arquivo.");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    aux = lista->inicio;
    while (aux != NULL) // percorre a lista
    {
        // posiciona o ponteiro do arquivo na posição do registro
        fseek (arq_bin_p, aux->pos * sizeof(registro), SEEK_SET);
        // faz a leitura do registro na posição
        fread(&reg, sizeof(registro),1 , arq_bin_p);
        printf("%s \n",reg.matricula);
        printf("%s \n",reg.nome);
        printf("%c \n",reg.genero);
        printf("%f \n",reg.salario);
        printf("%c \n",reg.cargo);
        printf("%s \n\n",reg.setor);

        aux = aux->prox; // avança para o próximo elemento da lista
    }
}

int main(){

    registro p[6],reg;
    tiplista *lista=(tiplista*)malloc(sizeof(tiplista));
    int pos=0;
    lista->inicio=NULL;
    lista->fim=NULL;

    p[0]=(const registro){"15101","Carlos",'M',2500.00,'A',"02"};
    p[1]=(const registro){"11256", "Ana", 'F', 1850.00, 'E', "01"};
    p[2]=(const registro){"11436", "Roberto", 'M', 1550.00, 'A', "51"};
    p[3]=(const registro){"11354", "José", 'M' ,1350.00, 'D', "04"};
    p[4]=(const registro){"12542", "Elaine", 'F', 2750.00, 'B', "22"};
    p[5]=(const registro){"00812", "Murilo", 'M', 3500.00, 'E', "01"};

    FILE *arq_bin_p=fopen("arq_bin_principal.bin","wb");
    fwrite(p, sizeof(registro),6,arq_bin_p);

    fclose(arq_bin_p);

    if((arq_bin_p=fopen("arq_bin_principal.bin","rb")) == NULL){
        printf("Erro: não foi possível encontrar o arquivo.");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fread(&reg,sizeof(registro),1,arq_bin_p)){

        insercao_lista_ordenada(lista,reg.nome,pos);
        pos++;
    }
    fclose(arq_bin_p);
    imprimir_lista(lista);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

O problema é que ao compilar esse programa ele só imprime 3 dos 6 registros do arquivo, e de alguma forma "reg.matricula" esta guardando a matricula e o nome juntos. No que eu estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite.

**reg.matricula guardando a matricula e o nome juntos**

`reg.matricula` não está guardando a matricula e o nome juntos. `reg.matricula` está sendo tratada como uma string, até aqui tudo bem, o problema é que ela não tem o `\0` para indicar seu final. Observe:

```
// Matricula tem 5 posições
char matricula[5];

// Então você atribui uma matricula para o Carlos
p[0]=(const registro){"15101","Carlos",'M',2500.00,'A',"02"};
```

Quando usamos aspas dupla para atribuir algo para um vetor de caracteres o `\0` fica no final, mas como `15101` tem o tamanho do vetor então o `\0` ficará de fora, na posição matricula[5].

> matricula[0] = '1'
>
> matricula[1] = '5'
>
> matricula[2] = '1'
>
> matricula[3] = '0'
>
> matricula[4] = '1'
>
> matricula[5] = '\0'

`matricula[5]` não faz parte do vetor `matricula` e aqui temos um problema. O interessante é que `matricula[5]` é onde seu vetor de nome inicia, isto é, `&matricula[5] == &nome[0]`. Então quando você adiciona um nome, o caractere `\0` vai ser substituído pela primeira letra do nome digitado. Um exemplo para o nome `Carlos`:

> matricula[5] = '\0' // Eh igual a nome[0]
>
> nome[0] = 'C' // '\0' foi substituído por 'C'
>
> nome[1] = 'a'
>
> nome[2] = 'r'
>
> nome[3] = 'l'
>
> nome[4] = 'o'
>
> nome[5] = 's'
>
> nome[6] = '\0'

Ao utilizar `%s`, no `printf`, para imprimir a matrícula, o programa vai percorrer tudo até encontrar um `\0`. O programa só vai parar quando o `\0` for encontrado, como o próximo `\0` é depois de `Carlos`, logo `Carlos` também será impresso. Para resolver isso basta deixar um local entre `char matricula[5];` e `char nome[50];`, nesse local ficará o `\0`. Basta fazer isso no seu código:

```
// Agora o '\0' ficará na matricula[5], que não faz parte do nome
// ou de qualquer outro lugar do seu programa, mas faz parte do vetor matricula
char matricula[6];
```

Lembre-se de deixar 1 espaço para o caractere `\0` quando for criar string. Se deseja um nome de `n` tamanho, então declare `n+1`.

**imprime 3 dos 6 registros**

O problema é na sua lista, nesse trecho em questão:

```
else if ((strcmp(aux->nome, nome)) < 0) // elemento a ser inserido maior
```

Essa parte do seu código sempre tem que ser verdadeira, caso contrário haverá `strings` que não irá para a lista. Perceba que antes desse `else if` você verifica se a `string` ficará no início. Bem, se a `string` não pode ficar no início então você precisa percorrer a lista para encontrar um local para ela, independentemente da string, ela vai ter que ser colocada na lista, se você faz um seleção com o `if`, então quem for reprovado por essa seleção (quando o `if` é falso) não vai entrar na lista. Como os códigos de inserção no final e no meio estão dentro do `if`, então só quem for aprovado irá para a lista e isso gera o erro lógico. Há 3 `string` que estão reprovando na seleção do `if` (são as 3 que não aparecem no `printf`) e por isso elas não estão entrando na sua lista.

Para resolver isso basta retirar o `if` e deixar somente o `else`. Exemplo:

```
// Remova isso
else if ((strcmp(aux->nome, nome)) < 0) // elemento a ser inserido maior

// E deixe assim
else
```

Seu código fica assim com essa duas alterações:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct registro
{
    //char matricula[5];
    char matricula[6];
    char nome[50];
    char genero;
    float salario;
    char cargo;
    char setor[2];
}registro;

typedef struct tiplista
{
    struct elem *inicio;
    struct elem *fim;
}tiplista;

typedef struct elem
{
    char nome[50];
    struct elem *ant;
    struct elem *prox;
    int pos; // posição do elemento no arquivo binário
}elem;

void insercao_lista_ordenada(tiplista *lista, char nome[50], int posicao)
{
    elem *aux;
    elem *novoelemento=(elem*)malloc(sizeof(elem));
    strcpy(novoelemento->nome,nome);
    novoelemento->prox= NULL;
    novoelemento->ant= NULL;
    novoelemento->pos=posicao;
    if(lista->inicio == NULL) //lista vazia
    {
        lista->inicio=novoelemento;
        lista->fim=novoelemento;
    }
    else
    {
        aux = lista->inicio; // pont aux recebe o ponteiro do início da lista
        while((aux->prox != NULL) && (strcmp(aux->nome, nome) < 0))
        {
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        // verificar se a inserção no início
        if((aux == lista->inicio) && ((strcmp(aux->nome, nome)) > 0))
        {
            novoelemento->prox = lista->inicio;
            lista->inicio->ant = novoelemento;
            lista->inicio = novoelemento;
        }
        // else if ((strcmp(aux->nome, nome)) < 0) // elemento a ser inserido maior
        else
        {
            // verificar se a inserção no final
            if (aux == lista->fim)
            {
                novoelemento->ant = lista->fim;
                lista->fim->prox = novoelemento;
                lista->fim = novoelemento;
            }
            else // inserção no meio
            {
                novoelemento->ant = aux->ant;
                aux->ant->prox = novoelemento;
                novoelemento->prox = aux;
                aux->ant = novoelemento;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

void imprimir_lista(tiplista *lista)
{
    elem *aux;
    registro reg;
    FILE *arq_bin_p;
    if((arq_bin_p=fopen("arq_bin_principal.bin","rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro: não foi possível encontrar o arquivo.");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    aux = lista->inicio;
    while (aux != NULL) // percorre a lista
    {
        // posiciona o ponteiro do arquivo na posição do registro
        fseek (arq_bin_p, aux->pos * sizeof(registro), SEEK_SET);
        // faz a leitura do registro na posição
        fread(&reg, sizeof(registro),1 , arq_bin_p);
        printf("%s \n",reg.matricula);
        printf("%s \n",reg.nome);
        printf("%c \n",reg.genero);
        printf("%f \n",reg.salario);
        printf("%c \n",reg.cargo);
        printf("%s \n\n",reg.setor);

        aux = aux->prox; // avança para o próximo elemento da lista
    }
}

int main()
{
    registro p[6],reg;
    tiplista *lista=(tiplista*)malloc(sizeof(tiplista));
    int pos=0;
    lista->inicio=NULL;
    lista->fim=NULL;

    p[0]=(const registro){"15101","Carlos",'M',2500.00,'A',"02"};
    p[1]=(const registro){"11256", "Ana", 'F', 1850.00, 'E', "01"};
    p[2]=(const registro){"11436", "Roberto", 'M', 1550.00, 'A', "51"};
    p[3]=(const registro){"11354", "José", 'M' ,1350.00, 'D', "04"};
    p[4]=(const registro){"12542", "Elaine", 'F', 2750.00, 'B', "22"};
    p[5]=(const registro){"00812", "Murilo", 'M', 3500.00, 'E', "01"};

    FILE *arq_bin_p=fopen("arq_bin_principal.bin","wb");
    fwrite(p, sizeof(registro),6,arq_bin_p);

    fclose(arq_bin_p);

    if((arq_bin_p=fopen("arq_bin_principal.bin","rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro: não foi possível encontrar o arquivo.");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fread(&reg,sizeof(registro),1,arq_bin_p))
    {
        insercao_lista_ordenada(lista,reg.nome,pos);
        pos++;
    }
    fclose(arq_bin_p);
    imprimir_lista(lista);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ajudou muito, vlw!!